# JQuery Mobile data-role initialization on a included html

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I have parent.html in whose one of the  i am including the child.html:

```
 $("#mydiv").load("child.html");
```

The problem here is the mobileinit is called at parent. The child.html only had a div with a data-role.

Is there a way to force data-role attribute to be rendered in the child.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobileinit is a event that is only triggered once in a JQuery mobile application lifecycle. If you load additional content you must manually trigger a pagecreate event instead.

```
$("#newPage").trigger('pagecreate');
```

Where "newPage" is the name of the page loaded inside child.html

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery **[load() function](https://api.jquery.com/load/)** has a callback for when it completes.  You should use that callback to trigger jQM's **[enhanceWithin() function](http://api.jquerymobile.com/enhanceWithin/)**:

```
$("#mydiv").load( "child.html", function() {
    $("#mydiv").enhanceWithin();
});
```